# Microsoft Chart Controls: how to set chart width to width of surrounding div?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-4.0, charts

Is it possible that a chart's width is inherited from its surrounding div?
How to do this (in the C# code behind or the ASP code)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe you can inherit the charts width from a Div, I'd set both using the codebehind.

You'll only have to wire this up once, per div and chart and then you can be assured that any future width changes will flow through to the chart.